# Need to get Oracle and Postgresql installed using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am a newbie to PowerShell. There was a requirement to get to know whether SQL, oracle, and PostgreSQL installed on a windows machine. I got for Oracle and used below command and got the result also.

```
$SQLInstalled = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product |
    Sort-object Name |
    select Name, version |
    Where { $_.Name -match 'SQL'}
).version

If (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($SQLInstalled))) { write-host 'Yes' }
Else { write-host 'No' }
```

But what would be for ORACLE as well as Postgresql? I tried the same above command it would not work.

Comment: If you install all of the software packages you mention on a windows machine, you could run "Get-WmiObject win32_product | Select Name" to list all software and pick the name from there. That name would then go where "SQL" is in your code above.

Comment: I tried to do that but it did not work. Have a system where Postgresql installed but its not listed in the above command which you mentioned.

Comment: Have you considered [checking the uninstall registry hive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx)?